# Generating a date in a table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, generate

I have a database in SQL which contains information about students and books they are borrowing.

I have a table of loans which includes the `book_id`, the `student_id`, the day the book was taken and the number of days the book can be kept.

I want to auto-generate the `return_date` by adding the days at the date in which the book was taken. How can I do this using MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MySQL datetime function `date_add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to compute the target `return_date`. Assuming that the date when the book was loaned is called `loan_date` and that the duration is stored in `loan_duration`, expressed in days:

```
select
    book_id,
    student_id,
    loan_date,
    date_add(loan_date, interval loan_duration day) return_date
from loan_table
```

In an update statement:

```
update loan_table
set return_date = date_add(loan_date, interval loan_duration day)
where return_date is null -- only compute the return_dates that were not yet computed
```

---

**Edit**

If you want that value to be *auto-generated*, an option is to use a generated stored (or virtual) column (available since MySQL 5.7). This works by defining a computation rule, that MySQL will automatically apply when a record is inserted or updated.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3893a6264bf3adb3cd5b04a2ff98ec6)**:

```
-- set up
create table loan_table(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    book_id int,
    student_id int,
    loan_date date,
    loan_duration int,
    -- here is the generated column
    return_date date 
        as (date_add(loan_date, interval loan_duration day)) stored
);

-- perform an insert
insert into loan_table(book_id, student_id, loan_date, loan_duration)
values(1, 1, '2019-11-02', 3)

-- check the computed value
select * from loan_table;
```

```
id | book_id | student_id | loan_date  | loan_duration | return_date
-: | ------: | ---------: | :--------- | ------------: | :----------
 1 |       1 |          1 | 2019-11-02 |             3 | 2019-11-05
```

Comment: I understand it, I can easily write this. I actually want to autogenerate it. For example when I insert in the table the loan_date and the number of days the column restore_date to update automatically. I want it to work like autoincrement for example.

Comment: @AdelinaK: OK. I updated my answer with a solution that suggests using a generated column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of interval and + :

```
select book_id
       , student_id
       , date_taken
       , number_od_days
       , (date_taken + interval number_od_days day) as return_date
from loans;
```

Here is the example in the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e88d7af98435fef4b23f72328bd6b724)

If you want this column to be auto incremented I suggest you create a trigger in your table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rentcheck 
BEFORE INSERT ON loans 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
    if new.number_od_days < 0 or new.number_od_days is null then
      signal sqlstate '45000';
    else
      set new.return_date = (new.date_taken + interval new.number_od_days day);
    end if;
end;
```

With it you can control if the column number_of_days will be negative or not entered because that would result with non logical data. Here is the demo for the trigger: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00aa119eab7385f93bd3372fc22137b9)

Answer (score 0):

you can use variables in mysql:

```
set @days = 10;
set @mydate := DATE_ADD("2019-11-01", INTERVAL @days DAY);
select @mydate;
```

and then use your insert statement:

```
Insert into Loan(... ,[return_date])
values (...., @mydate)
```

Hope it helps